# What is IMAP+? And how is it more advantageous over IMAP?

Tags: evolution, imap

In Evolution there is an option for an 'IMAP+' server type. What is IMAP+?

I noticed, if I choose IMAP+ for gmail account, two extra options appear in the receiving option tab:

1. `Use quick resync if the server supports it`
2. `Use idle if the server supports it`

What are these? And What are their advantages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simply a different implementation of IMAP in Evolution, which is supposed to be better in some cases than the standard IMAP implementation, which is the default. But it is not suitable for everyone just yet.

Quick resync and IDLE support are both features of some newer IMAP servers, which allow you to get an updated list of mails when they come in, without having to drop connection, reconnect, or re-fetch the entire list of mail for every folder. So if your server supports them, using them should make browsing your mail faster.